# Nginx, 403 for files containing some words but not opened from the admin folder

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I use these Nginx configuration option to prevent the opening of files containing -1000.jpg in the name:

```
location ~ \-1000\.jpg$ {
        return 403;
}
```

How to add the exception when opened from the folder `/admin/`. If I am in the `/admin/` folder (in the url) I would be able to open these files.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *negative lookahead assertion* in the regular expression to discard matches that begin with `/admin/`.

For example:

```
location ~ ^(?!/admin/).*-1000\.jpg$ { return 403; }
```